# In Android.mk, enabling OPENMP for arm64-v8a becomes slower?

Tags: android, openmp, neon, arm64, armv8

I would like to use OpenMP in my Android program. After searching online, I edited my Android.mk and added the OpenMP flag. However, without changing any code, the program runs slower. 
This issues happens only when I enabled OpenMP in armv8a.

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
LOCAL_CFLAGS     := -Werror -O3 -march=armv7-a
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=softfp -march=armv7 
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fopenmp
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -fopenmp
LOCAL_ARM_NEON  := true
else ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),arm64-v8a)
LOCAL_ARM_NEON  := true
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -march=armv8-a -Werror -O3
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fopenmp
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -fopenmp
```

Please help out if anyone knows the solution. I will really really really really appreciate it!

Comment: You might want to explain how you are testing and on what devices.

Comment: How many threads the application is using? What are the times? How did you added the pragmas to the code? You must provide the outlined parallel region with the respective pragmas in order to let us help you.

Comment: Why don't you post the disassembly of both openMP enabled and disabled? Looking at the generated machine code is so much better than guessing.